# Moment isAfter day

Tags: momentjs

So I need to check whether the current time is after a EndDate, which is a date stored as 19:00 UTC. I only need to know if it's the next day.

This is what I'm currently doing

```
const now = moment();
const tooLate = now.isAfter(moment(EndDate), 'day');
```

I worry about timezones. I supposedly need this for central time. Is this sufficient? Or do I need to worry about the timezone? As I understand it, moment runs in UTC to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the format of EndDate. By default `moment()` will parse in local time, so unless EndDate is a JS Date object, a unix timestamp (e.g. `1318781876406`), or in string form with UTC offset (e.g. `2013-02-08 09:30:26.123+07:00`) then you will have a problem if it is not in the same timezone as the client.

You can use [moment.UTC()](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) to parse in UTC time instead of local time. This should be enough to solve the any formatting problems you might have with EndDate